# Question about PHP PDO INFORMIX ERROR

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I have installed PDO_INFORMIX and CSDK already on CentOS5.6 32bits

and index.php have

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$db = new PDO("informix:host=172.30.179.81; service=5000;database=cms; EnableScrollableCursors=1", "myuser", "mypassword");
print("OK");
?>
```

but i still got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -11060 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]General error.' in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index3.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index3.php(5): PDO->__construct('informix:host=1...', 'myuser', 'mypassword') #1 {main} thrown in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index3.php on line 5
```

Have anyone know what it is ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to Informix database from this computer using other tools (like `dbaccess` or `isql` from unixodbc)?

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!  The standard technique for finding out more about errors is:

```
$ finderr -11060
-11060  General error.

An error occurred that has no specific SQL_STATE. In this case,
additional text is provided that identifies the source of the problem.
This IBM Informix CLI error code is the same as SQLSTATE value S1000.

$
```

That is not very helpful - to be polite about it.

- There are spaces in the connect string; does removing them help at all?
- Can you `telnet` to the host 172.30.179.81?
- Can you `telnet` to the port (service) 5000 on the host?
- Can you connect from this machine using any other Informix tool?
- Can you connect from other machines using the same connect string?

In case of desparation, can you track down whether all the shared libraries are loading correctly?